# EC2 instance region is not populated in user-data script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to fill some tags of the EC2 spot instance, however as it is impossible to do it directly in spot request, I do it via user data script. All is going fine when I specify region statically, but it is not universal approach. When I try to detect current region from instance userdata, the **region** variable is always empty. I do it in a following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
region=$(ec2-metadata -z | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
aws ec2 create-tags \
    --region $region \
    --resources `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` \
    --tags Key=sometag,Value=somevalue Key=sometag,Value=somevalue
```

I tried to made a delay before region populating

```
/bin/sleep 30
```

but this had no result.

However, when I run this script manually after start, the tags are added fine. What is going on?

Why all in all aws-cli doesn't get default region from profile? I have `aws configure` properly configured inside the instance, but without `--region` clause it throws error that region is not specified.

Comment: It's always good practice to fully-qualify paths in shell scripts.  When you run it manually, the environment is probably quite different, including `$PATH`... so you want `region=$(/usr/bin/ec2-metadata ...` (or wherever it is on your system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with

```
region=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | python -c "import json,sys; print"
```

which worked fine. However, it would be fine if somebody explain the nuts-and-bolts.

Comment: That is the URL via which the Amazon EC2 hypervisor provides [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). The request does not go across the network -- it is provided back to the instance directly. The `ec2-metadata` command simply calls that URL on your behalf, so the working result simply calls it directly. The document returns [information about the instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the `ec2-metadata` command is not available when your userdata script is executed. Try getting the region from the metadata server directly (which is what `ec2-metadata` does anyway)

```
region=$(curl -fsq http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone |  sed 's/[a-z]$//')
```

AWS CLI does use the region from default profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use this endpoint to get only the instance region (no parsing needed):

http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region

So in this case:

```
region=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/region`
```